# Visual Studio 2015 very slow debugging tests

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, automated-tests, mstest

I have tried:

- Clean and Build
- Enable 'Just My Code' symbol loading
- Disable Microsoft Symbol server and cache symbols
- Delete cache in  C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs
- Delete all breakpoints

The debugger attaches just fine but does not load the symbols for the test file until about 1m20s in. The output window does not do anything in this time but just before it starts working it reports having loaded in all my symbols.

Comment: Questions like these need to document the installed anti-malware product.

Comment: @koreus737, is it the coded UI test or other test type? Not debugging your test, just run it in the test explorer window, how about the result? We have to make sure that whether it is related to the test project or the debugging Environment. For general test project(C#), please also disable "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" under project property->Debug.

Comment: Thanks Hans, Jack. I have Sophos Anti Virus, the test runs in 2s from the test explorer when not debugging and it is not a UI test. I have also disabled 'Enable Visual Studio hosting process' to no avail.1

Comment: I used procman from sysinternals to look at what devenv.exe is doing during this time and it seems to be pounding \AppData\Local\Microsoft\ApplicationInsights\. Any ideas why it might be doing this?

Comment: PS: Our solution does not use Application Insights

Comment: Disabling send data to Microsoft under Help -> FeedBack -> settings has decreased the time by about 30s but its still really slow and devenv.exe is still slamming Application insights.

Comment: @ koreus737, do you debug the Azure app or ASP.NET app? I know that it has the option to enable the AI during you create the new app like ASP.NET, so whether you have enable it in default? https://1drv.ms/i/s!Auvjmr9ZOuhVhwu4H9L6iAJRz1SB, or you could find some threads which shared us how to disable the AI during debugging, I think you could get some useful information.

Comment: @koreus737, Could you disable the AI in your side?